# XMPP Chat works with client not within web

Tags: xmpp, chat, strophe

I've created a XMPP Chat Web application. If I chat between web and client it works perfectly fine. However, if I chat between two web windows it doesn't work properly. It shows only first message and then stops working. I need to refresh the page to restart working.
Any idea why is that?

Comment: You should show some code, or tell which libraries you are using. Without that info it's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same full JID (`user@domain/resource`) in both browser tabs?  If so, you've probably written the "dueling resources" bug.  You wouldn't be the first.

Comment: Hi, I got the solution. It was my mistake. I added event handler for 'on-message', but forgot to add 'return true' at the end. Because of which it received first message but then event handler was removed. Just added 'return true' and it worked. Thanks